# jquery ajax success callback difficulty

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have the following code:

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>
    Index</h2>
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        ...</div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <a id="btnShowCustomers" data-role="button" href="#secondDiv"></a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        ...</div>
</div>
<div id="secondDiv" data-role="page">
    <div id="list" data-role="content">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="customerDetailsDiv" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (event) {
        $('#btnShowCustomers').bind('vclick', function (event) {
            GetCustomers();
        });
    });

    function GetCustomers() {
        var webMethod = "Home/GetCustomers";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: webMethod,
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (dataObj) {
                $(dataObj).each(function () {
                    if ($(this).CanConsume) {
                        alert('can consume');
                        $('<a href="#" data-date="' + $(this).DateActivated + '" data-id="' + $(this).ID + '">' + $(this).Name + '</a>').appendTo('#list');
                    }
                })
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

From the server-side I'm returning a list of Customer objects. Customer has the following properties;

- ID
- CanConsume (bool)
- Name
- DateActivated

I want to iterate through the returned set of results and build anchor elements and append them to a div named list. Do you have any idea why this is not working? I get no javascript errors.

Comment: Your code will get a lot cleaner and less error prone if you leave the dirty html construction job to some javascript templating library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery kills errors... unfortunately.

If that does not work, please post some JSON.

damn to quick, again:

```
$.each(dataObj, function (index, element) {
    if (element.CanConsume) {
           alert('can consume');
           $('<a href="#" data-date="' + element.DateActivated + '" data-id="' + element.ID + '">' + element.Name + '</a>').appendTo('#list');
       }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`dataObj` is a normal list of plain JavaScript (JSON) objects. Don't use jQuery to iterate over that as jQuery.each(...) iterates over DOM elements.

Just try

```
   ...
   success: function(dataObj){
      for(var i=0; i < dataObj.length; i++){
         var obj = dataObj[i];
          if (obj.CanConsume) {
              alert('can consume');
              ...
          }
      }
   }
```

That should work.

Otherwise try [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or the Chrome Dev Tools to inspect the response or to set a breakpoint in your success callback. That should give you enough information to fix the problem.

Comment: Your answer was correct. I thought $.each() can be used to query anything :) I will mark your answer as correct as soon as 6 minutes expire. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question!